# Retrieving Youtube metadata on Android device

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am building an Android app that needs to know what the user is playing on Youtube in real time.

Is it possible to receive the Youtube metadata broadcast like you can with music apps?

Thanks